# multiplicacion de dos input en una fila

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una base de datos donde tengo varios campos, uno de ellos contiene un precio unitario.

Esta información la llevo a una tabla y el precio unitario lo multiplico con una cantidad ingresada en dicha fila para que me de el subtotal de esa fila. Esta operación la hace bien. El problema lo tengo cuando quiero corregir la cantidad de la fila anterior la cual me la multiplica con el precio unitario de la ultima fila y no de la fila correspondiente. espero haberme hecho entender.

```js
var lista=document.getElementById('lista');
var data=[];
var cant=0;
var cadena=""
boton.addEventListener("click", agregar);
let transactionFormData = new FormData(form);
form.reset();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/modal8',
    success: function (r) {
      dato = this.DataArray = r;
        if( (dato.modal8.length)>0){
         for (var i = 0; i < (dato.modal8.length); i++){
            cadena +="<option value="+(dato.modal8[i]['Id'])+">"+(dato.modal8[i]['username'])+"</option>"         
           }                     
        }     
    }
});


function agregar(){  
    for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++){ 
    var insumo = "insumo"  + cant;
    var txtID = "txtID"  + cant; 
    var username = "username" + cant;
    var password = "password" + cant;
    var email = "email" + cant;   
    var vunit = "vunit" + cant;
    var insumo=document.getElementById('insumo');
    txtID=document.getElementById('txtID');
    username=document.getElementById('username');
    password=document.getElementById('password');
    email=document.getElementById('email');
    var vunit=parseFloat(document.getElementById('vunit'));
    var cantidad=parseFloat(document.getElementById('cantidad').value);
    //agregar elemento al arreglo
    data.push(
        {
            "id":cant,
            "insumo":(insumo = "insumo"+cant),
            "txtID":(txtID = "txtID"+cant),
            "username":(username = "username"+cant),
           "password":(password ="password"+cant),
            "email":(email = "email" +cant),
            "vunit":(vunit = "vunit" +cant),
            "cantidad":cantidad=0,
            "total":total=0,
       }
            );
   var id_row='row'+cant;
   var fila='<tr id='+id_row+'><td><div class="container "><select onchange="Addatos(this.value,'+cant+')" name='+insumo+' id='+insumo+' class="form-select rounded-start-0" data-control="select2" data-placeholder="Select an option"><option selected></option>'+cadena+'</select></div></td><td><input id='+txtID+' type="text" class="form-control -sm" name='+txtID+' style="width: 70px;  text-align:center" placeholder="txtID"></td><td><input id='+username+' type="text" class="form-control -sm" style="width: 150px;" name='+username+' placeholder="Usuario"></td><td><input id='+password+' type="text" class="form-control -sm" style="width: 215px;" name='+password+' placeholder="Contraseña"></td><td><input id='+email+' type="email" class="form-control -sm "style="width: 290px;" name='+email+' placeholder="Correo"></td><td><input type="text"  id='+vunit+'  class="form-control -sm" style="width: 180px; text-align:right" name='+vunit+' value='+(f.format(vunit))+' placeholder="vunit"></input></td><td><input type="text" onkeyup="inputEvent(this.value,'+cant+')" align="right" id="cantidad"  class= "form-control table-input__value" style="width: 95px; text-align:center" name="cantidad" value='+cantidad+'></input></td><td><input align="right" id="Total" class="form-control -sm" style="width: 180px; text-align:right" name="Total" value='+(f.format(total))+' placeholder="Total"></input></td><td><a href="#" class="fa fa-trash " style="font-size:20px; color: red; margin-left: 30px;"  onclick="eliminar('+cant+')";></a></td><td><a href="#" class="fa fa-edit red-color" style="font-size:20px; margin-left: 30px;" onclick="cantidad('+cant+')";></a></td></tr></tr>';
   $("#lista").append(fila);  
    $("#vunit").val('');
    $("#cantidad").val('');
    $("#vunit").focus();
     cant++;
    sumarTotal();
   }
}
```

```js
function inputEvent(catx,row){
  const tableInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.table-input__value');
  tableInputs.forEach( input => {
    data[row].catx = catx;

    var total= data[row].catx*vunit;
    data[row].total=total;

    filaid=document.getElementById("row"+row);
    celda=filaid.getElementsByTagName('td');

    celda[7].innerHTML='<td><input id="Total" class="form-control -sm" style="width: 180px; text-align:right" name="Total" value='+(f.format(data[row].total))+' placeholder="Total" ></input></td>';

    sumarTotal();
      
  })
}
```

Comment: Al código le faltan cosas, como paréntesis y establecer donde empiezan / terminan las funciones (corchetes), asegúrate de agregar el código como es.

Comment: Recomiendo usar ``` tres de este símbolo para especificar un bloque de código. ` y que tu código se vea mejor formateado. Aquí en stack overflow usamos Markdown para formatear la pregunta, aprovéchalo y formatea tu pregunta de manera que quede agradable a la vista

Comment: gracias por responder. aqui esta el codigo mejor organizado. la celda[7] es donde llevo el subtotal de la multiplicacion

Comment: ha caracas, ¿Porque una edición tan fea?:0_o, Ahora ni descripción tiene. Déjame ver si consigo resolver tu problema.

Comment: gracias Daniel por tu valiosa ayuda

Comment: No entiendo tu código, usas un forEach pero ni la variable input usas... creo que tendría los mismos resultados si lo pones fuera del forEach. ¿El problema sucede al actualizar los datos o a penas recargas la página ahí está el problema?. Disculpa soy algo lento de para entender

Comment: Creo que aqui no yace el problema. Dejare que otro de la comunidad te ayude, tengo que hacer algo:(

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda Daniel

Comment: El codigo continua estando mal formateado. Debes formatear el codigo correctamente

Comment: @jhonnygomez cuando edites el código selecciona la opción de hacerlo como fragmento de código, asi podremos ejecutar tu código y entender mejor tu problema

Comment: Jhonnygomez ¿Nos enseñarías como actualizas los datos de la tabla?, no creo que el problema este en este código (a parte de que no usas la variable input y no se que es la variable data... pero supongo que es la fila)

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza, no he tenido mucho animo de programar estos dias

Comment: Daniel esta es la otra parte del codigo

Comment: Disculpa si ofende pero el código no es muy bueno, inicializas las variables innecesariamente para sobrescribirla y resobre escribirla sin hacer uso del valor anterior, y al parecer te gusta usar bucle cuando no es necesario (Realmente pienso que es innecesario este bucle porque haces una operación que no creo que quieras repetir:  for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++){ }. Otro error en tu codigo es que declaras la variable insumo y vuint dos veces.

Comment: Dicho lo anterior quita el bucle y como te va:)  (Digo que es el bucle porque le introduces dos veces los mismos datos a data por usar push(agregar al final del array))

Comment: Ha parte de lo anterior dicho, lo que queria ver era la funcion sumarTotal. Porque la llamas una vez por cada elemento con clase "table-input__value", y no se si eso acumula. (Me refiero por esta parte de codigo: let input=document.querySelectorAll('.table-input__value'); input.forEach(input=>{/*This.*/}); )

Comment: para nada me ofende. Estoy en este foro es para aprender, a veces no caemos en cuenta de nuestros propios errores hasta que alguien te los hace ver.

Comment: @DanielBriceño ten cuidado con las ediciones que realizas, bien podías poner el link de la página de ayuda aquí en los comentarios

Comment: @Christian No se, se me ocurrio hacer esto y tenia el tiempo para ello... Sera a la proxima. Jhonny Gomez, ¿funcionó?

Comment: no funciona. hace lo mismo